# Beautiful Soup not finding HTML that exists with file

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm looking at the Netflix jobs page: https://jobs.netflix.com/search

```
url = "https://jobs.netflix.com/search"

response=requests.get(url)
response = response.content
soup= BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

jobList = soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "css-160787d exb5qdx0"})
```

The last method is returning None and I don't understand why. I am reading the file in properly because I have checked.

I have tried both the find and find all with no success. I looked into using selenium but the website doesn't seem dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page is being hydrated from an API endpoint, via an XHR call. Here is one way of obtaining that information:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers= {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
url = 'https://jobs.netflix.com/api/search'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json(), record_path=['records', ['postings']])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    search_text     text    lever_id    state   updated_at  created_at  team    slug    location    external_id     ...     _index  _type   _score  _version    _explanation    sort    id  subteam     organization    alternate_locations
0   Amsterdam, Netherlands \r\n \r\n Creative Pro...    Senior Program Manager - Creative Production I...   c09326a8-eabe-49bc-844c-28fa3a3d6361    Public  2023-07-10T13:00:10+00:00   2023-07-10T09:38:57Z    [Creative Production]   senior-program-manager-creative-production-inn...   Amsterdam, Netherlands  284698346   ...     5e7cf522815a780d9124028c    _doc    None    None    None    None    64abd1f9b5811b900a89a18a    NaN     NaN     NaN
1   Manila, Philippines \r\n \r\n Netflix Technol...    Netflix IT Support Specialist   835f66aa-e7fc-46dc-a03d-5b39abf74afb    Public  2023-07-10T13:00:10+00:00   2023-07-10T08:26:19Z    [Netflix Technology Services]   netflix-it-support-specialist   Manila, Philippines     284690884   ...     5e7cf522815a780d9124028c    _doc    None    None    None    None    64abc190aabfb410a82540a4    [Netflix Technology Services]   NaN     NaN
2   Tokyo, Japan \r\n Corporate Functions \r\n Tal...   HR Associate - Japan    6bdf2520-bbb7-4e40-9f0e-c562fc6391e1    Public  2023-07-10T13:00:10+00:00   2023-07-10T05:43:57Z    [Talent and Recruiting]     hr-associate-japan  Tokyo, Japan    284673328   ...     5e7cf522815a780d9124028c    _doc    None    None    None    None    64ab9ae37a9df82a8330ae9d    [Human Resources]   [Corporate Functions]   NaN
3   Remote, California \r\n Corporate Functions \r...   People Scientist    1ba707a0-8bb2-436d-921a-1a985dd7fd5b    Public  2023-07-10T13:00:10+00:00   2023-07-07T17:59:45Z    [Talent and Recruiting]     people-scientist    Remote, California  284310527   ...     5e7cf522815a780d9124028c    _doc    None    None    None    None    64a87cdaaabfb4e0b925418d    [Human Resources]   [Corporate Functions]   NaN
4   Remote, United States \r\n \r\n Core Engineer...    Software Engineer (L5) - Ads Revenue Infrastru...   0e733d7e-3a0a-4dd5-ab5e-51c970b484e3    Public  2023-07-10T13:00:10+00:00   2023-07-07T15:50:51Z    [Core Engineering]  software-engineer-l5-ads-revenue-infrastructure     Remote, United States   284278602   ...     5e7cf522815a780d9124028c    _doc    None    None    None    None    64a8368db5811b243289a8dc    [Content Engineering Core]  NaN     NaN
5   Remote, United States \r\n Games \r\n Boss Fig...   Director of Game Development    46b233f1-8fff-4052-ac70-94f1e5ff6372    Public  2023-07-10T13:00:10+00:00   2023-07-03T23:29:19Z    [Boss Fight Entertainment]  director-of-game-development    Remote, United States   283904007   ...     5e7cf522815a780d9124028c    _doc    None    None    None    None    64a950f83d6b6272441b736d    NaN     [Games]     NaN
6   Remote, United States \r\n Corporate Functions...   Executive Coach     c1a8ea67-fb0a-498d-8296-5929f1a2555a    Public  2023-07-10T13:00:10+00:00   2023-06-30T21:04:51Z    [Talent and Recruiting]     executive-coach     Remote, United States   283427947   ...     5e7cf522815a780d9124028c    _doc    None    None    None    None    649f44af3d6b62a03c7c6f7c    [Human Resources]   [Corporate Functions]   NaN
7   Los Gatos, California \r\n Corporate Functions...   Business Process Analyst, Finance   f1078eb0-bf61-4f03-82f2-2b7c1c786830    Public  2023-07-10T13:00:10+00:00   2023-06-30T14:32:35Z    [Finance]   business-process-analyst-finance    Los Gatos, California   283385129   ...     5e7cf522815a780d9124028c    _doc    None    None    None    None    649ee81ab5811b9d27624638    [Finance]   [Corporate Functions]   [Los Angeles, California]
8   Seoul, South Korea \r\n Corporate Functions \r...   Senior Manager - Country Lead, Production Fina...   8e35e3d6-f762-4b53-99e8-6cc62f1875db    Public  2023-07-10T13:00:14+00:00   2023-06-30T05:25:07Z    [Finance]   senior-manager-country-lead-production-finance...   Seoul, South Korea  283325929   ...     5e7cf522815a780d9124028c    _doc    None    None    None    None    649e6863aabfb4704f86b47f    [Finance]   [Corporate Functions]   NaN
9   Singapore, Singapore \r\n Marketing and Public...   Manager, Ads B2B Marketing - APAC   f3275e7e-38af-4bb6-84b6-a99094738986    Public  2023-07-10T13:00:10+00:00   2023-06-29T05:21:12Z    [Partner Marketing]     manager-ads-b2b-marketing-apac  Singapore, Singapore    283167491   ...     5e7cf522815a780d9124028c    _doc    None    None    None    None    649d15b5aabfb4551aed6809    NaN     [Marketing and Publicity]   NaN
10  Mumbai, India \r\n Content \r\n \r\n \r\n Ma...     Manager, Series - India     9a630609-3041-4698-a95d-543efe80a93c    Public  2023-07-10T13:00:10+00:00   2023-06-29T02:52:34Z    NaN     manager-india-series-and-films  Mumbai, India   283151020   ...     5e7cf522815a780d9124028c    _doc    None    None    None    None    64a502957a9df822a932aa71    NaN     [Content]   NaN
11  Remote, United States \r\n \r\n Data Science ...    Data Science and Analytics Manager - Streaming...   ecf66443-f3cf-4ded-ab7b-c3ed84a2b348    Public  2023-07-10T13:00:17+00:00   2023-06-29T00:32:39Z    [Data Science and Engineering]  data-science-and-analytics-manager-streaming-p...   Remote, United States   283135676   ...     5e7cf522815a780d9124028c    _doc    None    None    None    None    649cd1beb5811bc57c7eeed6    [Data Science and Engineering]  NaN     NaN
12  Remote, United States \r\n \r\n Creative Prod...    Regional Planning Lead - UCAN   4e8eb40e-c4fb-4775-b9f1-620c5fcc3f87    Public  2023-07-10T13:00:10+00:00   2023-06-28T22:42:58Z    [Creative Production]   regional-planning-lead-ucan     Remote, United States   283123645   ...     5e7cf522815a780d9124028c    _doc    None    None    None    None    649cb7f23d6b62cec27a7039    [Product Creative Core]     NaN     NaN
13  Amsterdam, Netherlands \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n ...  Manager, Finance Strategy & Analysis (FS&A) , ...   4c920cf4-1bd5-4630-9833-c16c7c3cac12    Public  2023-07-10T13:00:17+00:00   2023-06-28T08:44:17Z    NaN     manager-revenue-analytics   Amsterdam, Netherlands  283031908   ...     5e7cf522815a780d9124028c    _doc    None    None    None    None    64a587cf7a9df89cbdc9f25d    NaN     NaN     NaN
14  Los Angeles, California \r\n Marketing and Pub...   AV Producer - UCAN  2c76fb58-8c56-442e-98be-028889094b0c    Public  2023-07-10T13:00:10+00:00   2023-06-27T23:13:25Z    [Creative Marketing Production]     av-producer-ucan    Los Angeles, California     282969550   ...     5e7cf522815a780d9124028c    _doc    None    None    None    None    649b6d7aaabfb4675b853b6d    [Marketing Production]  [Marketing and Publicity]   NaN
15  Manila, Philippines \r\n Corporate Functions \...   AP Invoice Processing Specialist, Manila (Japa...   bd698f4b-aac7-46d7-9087-053f077e05d7    Public  2023-07-10T13:00:10+00:00   2023-06-27T02:45:47Z    [Finance]   ap-invoice-processing-specialist-manila-japane...   Manila, Philippines     282835505   ...     5e7cf522815a780d9124028c    _doc    None    None    None    None    649a4e5d3d6b62657a2b93c7    [Finance]   [Corporate Functions]   NaN
16  Manila, Philippines \r\n Corporate Functions \...   Accounts Payable Invoice Processing Specialist...   e0048b97-2c8b-4ae3-8fe8-a88e8c17b210    Public  2023-07-10T13:00:10+00:00   2023-06-27T01:41:20Z    [Finance]   ap-invoice-processing-specialist-manila     Manila, Philippines     282828368   ...     5e7cf522815a780d9124028c    _doc    None    None    None    None    649a3f22b5811b71eb80f9c4    [Finance]   [Corporate Functions]   NaN
17  Dallas, Texas \r\n Games \r\n Boss Fight Enter...   IT Support Specialist - Boss Fight Entertainment    2d3c4f18-4f81-46ea-a8e8-b402865c47ab    Public  2023-07-10T13:00:10+00:00   2023-06-26T23:39:17Z    [Boss Fight Entertainment]  it-support-specialist-boss-fight    Dallas, Texas   282814656   ...     5e7cf522815a780d9124028c    _doc    None    None    None    None    649b052eaabfb4f2708532c6    NaN     [Games]     NaN
18  Los Gatos, California \r\n Games \r\n Netflix ...   Player Support Lead, Netflix Games Studio   3a3aa925-861a-4567-a367-8c9ce9edf2bc    Public  2023-07-10T13:00:10+00:00   2023-06-26T16:26:37Z    [Netflix Games Studio]  player-support-lead-netflix-games-studio    Los Gatos, California   282767770   ...     5e7cf522815a780d9124028c    _doc    None    None    None    None    6499bd167a9df88c1302b79a    NaN     [Games]     NaN
19  Warsaw, Poland \r\n Corporate Functions \r\n T...   HR Business Partner, CEE    4abd34d0-c9a3-4469-8533-f757c2b65063    Public  2023-07-10T13:00:17+00:00   2023-06-23T16:13:14Z    [Talent and Recruiting]     hr-business-partner-cee     Warsaw, Poland  282717815   ...     5e7cf522815a780d9124028c    _doc    None    None    None    None    649951413d6b626dab2b8129    [Human Resources]   [Corporate Functions]   NaN

20 rows × 22 columns
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't completely understand why it works though.

Comment: That page is dynamic, and the scripts from it are pulling various bits of information from various places.